# fallos al manejar un objeto

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy creando una página para almacenar la información de varios discos, que está unida a una base de datos phpmyadmin.
Insertar me funciona, pero al consultar, editar, buscar y borrar no me encuentra bien el objeto creado.
Este es el archivo index_discos.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gestor de discos</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            <!--input{
                font-family:Arial,Helvetica;
                font-size:14;
                color:#000033;
                font-weight:normal;
                border-color:#999999;
                border-width:1;
                background-color:#FFFFFF;
            }-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#C0C0C0" link="blue" vlink="blue" alink="blue">
        <font face="arial,helvetica">
            <table border="0" align="center" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3" width="650">
                <tr><th colspan="2" width="100%" bgcolor="blue"><font size="6" color="white">Gestor de Discos</font></th>
                </tr></table><p>
<?php
    require("discos.php");
    $los_discos=new discos();
    echo "<center><p>
        <table border='0' width='600'><tr>
            <td valign=top align=center colspan=2>
                <form name='form1' mrthod='post' action=\"index_discos.php?operacion=buscar\">
                <font size ='-1'>Buscar por el campo <select name='campo_busqueda'>
                <option ";
            if((isset($_REQUEST["campo_busqueda"]))&&($_REQUEST["campo_busqueda"]=='titulo')) echo "selected";
            echo "Value=titulo>Título</option><option ";
            if((isset($_REQUEST["campo_busqueda"]))&&($_REQUEST["campo_busqueda"]=='interprete')) echo "selected";
            echo " Value=interprete>Intérprete</option></select>";
            if(!isset($_REQUEST["lo_q_busco"])) $_REQUEST["lo_q_busco"]="";
            echo "<p><input type='text' name='lo_q_busco' value='".$_REQUEST["lo_q_busco"]."' size='20'>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='boton_buscar' value='Buscar!'>
                </font>
                </form>
            </td><td align=center>
                <form name='form2' method='post' action='index_discos.php?operacion=introduce&ver=0&nume=0#ancla'>
                <input type='submit' name='alta' value=\"Nuevo disco\">
                </form>
                <form name='form3' method='post' action='index_discos.php?operacion=listado'>
                <input type='submit' name='alta' value='Listado completo'>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr></table>";
    if(isset($_REQUEST["operacion"])){
        if($_REQUEST["operacion"]=="listado") $los_discos->buscar("","titulo");
        elseif($_REQUEST["operacion"]=="buscar") $los_discos->buscar($_REQUEST["lo_q_busco"],$_REQUEST["campo_busqueda"]);
        elseif($_REQUEST["operacion"]=="introduce"){//ventana de alta o edición
            if($_REQUEST["ver"]==1) $caption="Datos del disco";
            else if($_REQUEST["nume"]>0) $caption="Modificar disco";
            else $caption="Alta de nuevo disco";
            echo "<p><hr><a name='ancla'></a><font color='blue' size=+1>$caption</font>";
            $los_discos->introduce($_REQUEST["nume"],$_REQUEST["ver"]);
        }elseif($_REQUEST["operacion"]=="exec_alta"){
            if($_REQUEST["titulo"]=="")
                echo "<center>No se puede realizar la operación: el campo 'Título' es obligatorio.</center><p>";
            elseif($_REQUEST["interprete"]=="")
                echo "<center>No se puede realizar la operación: el campo 'Intérprete' es obligatorio.</center><p>";
            else{
                $los_discos->add_disco($_REQUEST["registro"],$_REQUEST["titulo"],$_REQUEST["interprete"],$_REQUEST["estilo"],$_REQUEST["casa_discografica"],$_REQUEST["formato"],$_REQUEST["duracion"],$_REQUEST["anio"],$_FILES['imagen']);
                if($_REQUEST["registro"]>0) $caption="modificado";
                else $caption="dado de alta";
                echo "<p><center><font color='blue'> Se ha $caption correctamente el disco:<b>".$_REQUEST["titulo"]."</b> del intérprete <b>".$_REQUEST["interprete"]."</b></font></center><p>";
            }
        }elseif($_REQUEST["operacion"]=="borrar") $los_discos->del_disco($_REQUEST["nume"]);
    }else
        $los_discos->buscar("","titulo");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es el archivo discos.php:

```
<?php
    function boton_ficticio($caption,$url){
        return "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3 bgcolor=black>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor='white'>
                    <font size='-1'>
                        <a href='$url'>$caption</a>
                    </font>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
    }
    define("SERVIDOR","localhost");
    define("USUARIO","root");
    define("CLAVE","");
    class discos{
        protected $db;
        function __construct($BD=""){
            try{
                if($BD!='')
                    $this->db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";dbname=".$BD.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                else
                    $this->db=new PDO("mysql:host=".SERVIDOR.";charset=utf8",USUARIO,CLAVE,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY,true);
                $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::NULL_TO_STRING,true);
                if($BD==''){
                    $sql=file_get_contents('bases de datos.sql');
                    $this->ejecuta_SQL($sql);
                }
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die("<p><h3>No se ha podido establecer la conexión.
                    <p>Compruebe si está activado el servidor de bases de
                    datos MySQL.</h3></p>\n<p>Error: ".$e->getMessage()."</p>\n");
            }
        }
        function __destruct(){
            if(isset($db))
                $db=null;
        }
        function add_disco($registro,$titulo,$interprete,$estilo,$casa_discografica,$formato,$duracion,$anio,$imagen){
            if(isset($imagen)&&($imagen['size']>0)){
                if($imagen['size']>80000)
                    die("<b>El fichero ocupa más de 80KB o no ha indicado su nombre en el formulario. No puede copiarse.</b>");
                if(is_uploaded_file($imagen['tmp_name'])&&!empty($imagen['tmp_name'])){
                    $tipo_fichero=explode("/",$imagen['type']);
                    if($tipo_fichero[0]=='image'){
                        if($registro>0){
                            $sql_script="SELECT imagen FROM discos WHERE id='$registro'";
                            $resultado=$this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
                            $filas=$resultado->rowCount();
                            if($filas==0){
                                echo "<center>
                                    <table border=1 width=600 bordercolorlight='#FFFFFF' bordercolor='#FFFFFF' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'>
                                    <tr><td align=center valign=middle>
                                    <font size=+2>No se encuentra ningún registro</font>
                                    </td></tr></table></center>";
                            }else{
                                $myrow=$resultado->fetch_row();
                                if($imagen['name']<>$myrow[0]){
                                    $sql_script="SELECT id FROM discos WHERE imagen='".$myrow[0]."'";
                                    $this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
                                    if($filas==1){
                                        unlink("imagenes/".$myrow[0]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        move_uploaded_file($imagen['tmp_name'],'imagenes/'.$imagen['name']);
                    }else die("<b>Sólo se pueden subir ficheros de tipo imagen.</b>");
                }else die("<b>No se puede subir el fichero.</b>");
            }
            if($registro>0)
                $sql_script="UPDATE discos SET
                titulo='$titulo',interprete='$interprete',estilo='$estilo',
                casa_discografica='$casa_discografica',formato='$formato',
                duracion='$duracion',anio='$anio',imagen='".$imagen['name']."'
                WHERE id=$registro";
            else
                $sql_script="INSERT INTO discos
                (titulo,interprete,estilo,casa_discografica,formato,duracion,anio,imagen)
                VALUES('$titulo','$interprete','$estilo','$casa_discografica','$formato','$duracion','$anio','".$imagen['name']."')";
            $this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
            $this->buscar("","titulo");
        }
        function nume_discos(){
            $sql_script="SELECT * FROM discos";
            $resultado=$this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
            $filas=$resultado->rowCount();
            return $filas;
        }
        function del_disco($id_to_del){
            $sql_script="SELECT imagen FROM discos WHERE id='$id_to_del'";
            $resultado=$this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
            $filas=$resultado->rowCount();
            if($filas==0){
                echo "<center>
                    <table border=1 width=600 bordercolorlight='#FFFFFF' bordercolor='#FFFFFF' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'>
                    <tr><td align=center valign=middle>
                    <font size=+2>No se encuentra ningún registro</font>
                    </td></tr></table></center>";
            }else{
                $myrow=$resultado->fetch_row();
                $sql_script="SELECT id FROM discos WHERE imagen='".$myrow[0]."'";
                $resultado=$this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
                $filas=$resultado->rowCount();
                if($filas==1){
                    unlink("imagenes/".$myrow[0]);
                }
            }
            $sql_script="delete FROM discos WHERE id=$id_to_del";
            $this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
            $this->buscar("","titulo");
        }
        function introduce($id_to_edit,$ver){
            $campos=array(
                    0=>array(0=>"titulo",1=>"Título",2=>40,3=>100,4=>""),
                    1=>array(0=>"interprete",1=>"Intérprete",2=>30,3=>50,4=>""),
                    2=>array(0=>"estilo",1=>"Estilo",2=>30,3=>50,4=>""),
                    3=>array(0=>"casa_discografica",1=>"Casa Discográfica",2=>30,3=>50,4=>""),
                    4=>array(0=>"formato",1=>"Formato (CD/MC)",2=>30,3=>50,4=>""),
                    5=>array(0=>"duracion",1=>"Duración (min)",2=>3,3=>3,4=>""),
                    6=>array(0=>"anio",1=>"Año prod.",2=>4,3=>4,4=>""),
                    7=>array(0=>"imagen",1=>"Imagen",2=>15,3=>-1,4=>""));
            if($id_to_edit>0){
                $sql_script="SELECT
                titulo,interprete,estilo,casa_discografica,formato,duracion,anio,imagen
                FROM discos WHERE id='$id_to_edit'";
                $resultado=$this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
                $filas=$resultado->rowCount();
                if($filas==0){
                    echo "<center>
                        <table border=1 width=600 bordercolorlight='#FFFFFF' bordercolor='#FFFFFF' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'>
                        <tr><td align=center valign=middle>
                        <font size=+2>No se encuentra ningún registro</font>
                        </td></tr></table></center>";
                }else{
                    $myrow=$resultado->fetch();
                    for($i=0;$i<count($campos);$i++)
                        $campos[$i][4]=$myrow[$i];
                }
            }
            if($ver==0)
                echo "<form name='form9' enctype=multipart/form-data method='post' action=\"index_discos.php?operacion=exec_alta\">";
                echo "<table border='0' cellspacing='10' cellpadding='0' align='center' width='600'>";
                for($i=0;$i<count($campos);$i++){
                    echo "<tr><td bgcolor='blue' align=center width=140>
                        <font size=-1 color='white'>".$campos[$i][1]."</font>
                        </td><td>";
                    if($ver==1){
                        if($campos[$i][3]>-1) echo "<font size=-1><b>".$campos[$i][4]."</b></font>";
                        else if($campos[$i][4]<>'') echo "<IMG src='imagenes/".$campos[$i][4].">";
                        else echo "<font size=-1><b>Sin imagen</b></font>";
                    }else
                        if($campos[$i][3]>-1)
                            echo "<input type='text' name='".$campos[$i][0]."' size='".$campos[$i][2]."' value=\"".$campos[$i][4]."\" maxlength='".$campos[$i][3]."'>";
                        else
                            echo "<input type='file' name='".$campos[$i][0]."' size='".$campos[$i][2]."'><input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='80000'>";
                    echo "</td></tr>";
                }//for
                echo "</table><center>";
                if($ver==0){
                    echo "<input type='hidden' name='registro' value='$id_to_edit'>";
                    if($id_to_edit>0)
                        echo "<input type='submit' name='pulsa' value=\"Modificar disco\">";
                    else
                        echo "<input type='submit' name='pulsa' value=\"Alta disco\">";
                }
                echo "</center>";
                if($ver==0) echo "</form>";
        }
        function buscar($lo_q_busco,$campo_busqueda){
            $sql_script="SELECT * FROM discos
                WHERE ".$campo_busqueda." like '%".$lo_q_busco."%'
                ORDER BY ".$campo_busqueda;
            $resultado=$this->ejecuta_SQL($sql_script);
            $filas=$resultado->rowCount();
            if($filas==0){
                echo "<center>
                    <table border=1 width=650 bordercolorlight='#FFFFFF' bordercolor='#FFFFFF' bgcolor='#C0C0C0'>
                    <tr><td align=center valign=center>
                    <h2>No se encuentra ningún registro</h2>
                    </td></tr></table></center>";
            }else
                echo "<table border='0' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='1' align='center' width='650'>
                    <tr>
                        <th bgcolor='blue'><font color='white'>T&iacute;tulo</font></th>
                        <th bgcolor='blue'><font color='white'>Int&eacute;rprete</font></th>
                        <th bgcolor='blue'><font color='white'>Estilo</font></th>
                        <th bgcolor='blue'><font color='white'>Casa Disco</font></th>
                        <th bgcolor='blue' colspan='3'><fontT color='white'>Operaciones</font></th>
                        </tr>";
                    while($myrow=$resultado->fetch()){
                        echo "<tr>
                            <td><font size='-1'><b>".$myrow[1]."</b></font></td>
                            <td><font size='-1'><b>".$myrow[2]."</b></font></td>
                            <td><font size='-1'><b>".$myrow[3]."</b></font></td>
                            <td><font size='-1'><b>".$myrow[4]."</b></font></td>
                            <td>".boton_ficticio("Consulta","index_discos.php?operacion=introduce&ver=1&nume=".$myrow[0]."#ancla")."</td>
                            <td>".boton_ficticio("Editar","index_discos.php?operacion=introduce&ver=0&nume=".$myrow[0]."#ancla")."</td>
                            <td>".boton_ficticio("Borrar","index_discos.php?operacion=borrar&nume=".$myrow[0])."</td>
                            </tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table><p>
                    <table><tr>
                    <td><font color=blue size='-1'>El nº total de discos es: ".$this->nume_discos()."</font><p></td>
                    </tr></table>";
        }
        function ejecuta_SQL($sql){
            $resultado=$this->db->query($sql);
            if(!$resultado){
                echo"<h3>No se ha podido ejecutar la consulta: <pre>$sql</pre><p><u> Errores</u>: </h3><pre>";
                print_r($this->db->errorInfo());
                die ("</pre>");
            }
            return $resultado;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué quiere decir que *`no me encuentra bien el objeto creado`*? Ante un código largo conviene que seas más explícito en cuanto al comportamiento del mismo. ¿Has depurado objetos, variables, conexiones? ¿Has depurado consultas en la base de datos misma? ¿Has depurado si los datos existen realmente? etc

Comment: Al poner en el campo de búsqueda un trozo de texto que aparece en un titulo o en un interprete, no me aparece ningún resultado en la pantalla. Además, a la hora de editar o consultar un disco, aparecen los campos vacíos. He probado poniendo la consulta de búsqueda en la página de consultas de PhpMyAdmin y funciona bien.

Comment: ¿De qué función en específico hablas, para poder ubicarnos mejor y empezar a detectar dónde está el fallo? ¿Cuando dices que no aparece nada, es nada, ni siquiera un mensaje de error? ¿En tu código hay control para cuando la conexión o las consultas fallen o no traigan datos?

Comment: En index_discos.php, nada mas empezar el código php, está donde coloco el campo de búsqueda y el botón buscar. En discos.php, en el método buscar (es el penúltimo método) creo que tiene que estar algo mal. Pero he puesto todo, porque, al no funcionar el editar y consultar, creo que debe haber algo más mal que yo no detecto.

Comment: Bueno... es algo difícil adentrarse en tu código si no indicas más claramente el asunto. Según tu último comentario, ¿el problema es al enviar este formulario?: `<form name='form1' mrthod='post' action=\"index_discos.php?operacion=buscar\">` ahí ya tenemos un problema: **tienes mal escrita la palabra `method`**, pues lo que aparece escrito es esto: `mrthod` ... Corrige eso y si no funciona sigue dando más detalles porque como te digo, tu código no es muy *apetecible*, no es fácil meterse a analizar un código que no has escrito y mucho menos con tanta mezcla de cosas en él.

Comment: Tenías razón, ese error no dejaba buscar bien. Pero el otro error no se ha arreglado. Al intentar consultar o editar un disco aparecen vacíos los campos del disco

Comment: Bien. Vamos a buscar en tu código dónde ocurre eso. De paso, considera empezar a aplicar buenas prácticas de programación en algunos aspectos. Por ejemplo, evita poner reglas de estilo directamente en los elementos, usando clases CSS. Eso te permitirá liberar tu código de tanta verbosidad y no solo eso, sino que cambiar cualquier estilo será mucho más fácil. Evita también usar `REQUEST` por todos lados, cuando uses `POST` en los formularios, usa `POST` al recuperar los datos, si es `GET` usa `GET`.  Deberías también implementar consultas preparadas y separar código, tienes todo mezclado.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona ahora, el `form2` o es el `form3` o cuál es?  ¿No muestra nada, ni error ni nada? Aquí por ej: `<form name='form2' method='post' action='index_discos.php?operacion=introduce&ver=0&nume=0#ancla'>` tienes una URL **rarísima**. ¿qué significa ese `#ancla`, qué quieres hacer ahí?

Comment: Es en los botones comentar y editar de cada disco que creo yo, porque en los que ya hay guardados en la base de datos, sí que los muestra bien. Los formularios van bien.

Comment: ¿Los botones comentar y editar?  ¿Dónde están esos botones específicamente?

Comment: En el mismo método buscar de antes.

Comment: Sinceramente te recomendaría que empieces a separar código. Con todo respeto, tienes tal lío en ese código que es muy difícil aclararse. Los envíos que haces por POST no estoy seguro que funcionen bien como lo estás haciendo, usando algo tan precario como marcadores añadidos al final de la URL del post, por ejemplo ese dichoso `#ancla` que tienes. Date cuenta de que tus operaciones serían inmesamente sencillas usando Ajax y usando en PHP algo así como clases que gestionen por separado cada operación del CRUD: crear, leer, actualizar, borrar. Luego puedes unir cada pieza cuando sea necesario...

Comment: ... si quieres, antes de hacer una separación tan avanzada como te propongo, dado que ahora tienes todo mezclado, al menos gestiona las cosas en funciones, no usando marcadores cooomo el dicho `#ancla`. O sea, en el POST pon una clave por cada operación, luego buscas si esa clave está y en base a ello llama una de tus funciones de CRUD. Es necesario que organices el código así, sino es imposible que te funcione bien, pues tienes todo mezclado. Cuando el archivo se recarga el busca lo que hay en el POST y no estoy seguro que eso del marcador funcione bien.

Comment: estoy en un curso de Aula Mentor y me han enseñado así. Ya se que es código obsoleto y mal estructurado, pero es lo que áhi. Por cierto, que me decían de hacerlo con métodos de php 5 y he tenido que pasar todo a php 7 por mi cuenta, buscando por internet

Comment: Bueno, pero en el curso no creo que te impidan usar funciones. Por ejemplo, puedes tener estas funciones: `create()`, `read()`, `update()`, `delete()`. En cada formulario tú pones en la URL una clave (como estás haciendo), por ejemplo: `index_discos.php?operacion=create...`, o `index_discos.php?operacion=read...` luego, **evalúas el POST una sola vez, no 50,000 veces**, por ej. `$operacion=$_POST["operacion"];` y luego haces un `switch... case` para llamar a una de tus funciones según la operación demandada. No sé si me entiendes lo que quiero decirte. Así ya te quitas de encima parte del lío.

Comment: Si, si te entiendo, mañana empezaré a hacerlo así. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda.